# I have a question about the high chart data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Good morning. I hope you understand even if the question is weird because I speak English wrong.

I am curious how to change the data of high chart with a for statement.

I want to make it disappear from the chart when the y value of the data is empty, but it doesn't work. Help

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var label = [];
    var cnt=[];
    <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="item">
        label.push('${item.LABEL}');
        cnt.push(Number('${item.CNT}'));
    </c:forEach>
    
    $("#organDealCountChart").highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,      //하이차트 url 숨기기
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.y}건'
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function(){
                        if (!this.y) 
                            return ;
                        else
                            return this.point.name + ": " + this.point.percentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: label[0],
                y: cnt[0]
            }, {
                name: label[1],
                y: cnt[1]
            }, {
                name: label[2],
                y: cnt[2]
            }, {
                name: label[3],
                y: cnt[3]
            }, {
                name: label[4],
                y: cnt[4]
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @min, What do you mean that data is empty? Could you provide me with a sample of the `cnt` vaiable after forEach loop?